# update RecyclerView with SwipeRefresh from database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

i'm trying to get updated data from database on Refresh 
in onCreate the returned data is right and when i Refresh it seems that the returned data also right (in Toast ) but gui doesn't refresh with new data
what i did wrong !!

```
public class NewsPage extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private RecyclerView rv;
private rvAdapter adapter;
public static ArrayList<String> Descriptions = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> FullText = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<rvData> data = new ArrayList<>();
public static int[] icons = {R.drawable.day7, R.drawable.day7, R.drawable.day7, R.drawable.day7, R.drawable.day7};
public static ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
public  SwipeRefreshLayout strID;
GridTagsAdapter gridTagsAdapter;
public   String tags[] = { "#???? ?????","#???? ???","#????? ?????","#???? ????" , "#????? ????????"};



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_screen, container, false);
    strID = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.strID);
    strID.setOnRefreshListener(this);


     strID.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {


              JSONTask asyncTask = (JSONTask) new JSONTask(new JSONTask.AsyncResponse(){


        @Override
        public void processFinish(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> output) {


               strID.setRefreshing(true);

            Descriptions = output.get(0);
            titles = output.get(1);
            ids = output.get(2);
            FullText = output.get(3);


            rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.NewsScreen);
            adapter = new rvAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                strID.setRefreshing(false);


        }
    }).execute("http://192.168.1.106:8000/database/news/g/?format=json");
         }
     });





    return v;
}





public List<rvData> getData() {

    for (int i = 0; i < Descriptions.size(); i++) {
        rvData current = new rvData();
        current.titleid = titles.get(i);
        current.postbodyid = Descriptions.get(i);
        current.imgid = icons[0];
        gridTagsAdapter   = new GridTagsAdapter(getActivity(),tags);
        current.tags_adapter= gridTagsAdapter;
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}


@Override
public void onRefresh() {

     JSONTask asyncTask = (JSONTask) new JSONTask(new JSONTask.AsyncResponse(){


        @Override
        public void processFinish(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> output) {


            strID.setRefreshing(true);

            Descriptions.clear();
            titles.clear();
            ids.clear();
            FullText.clear();

            Descriptions = output.get(0);
            titles = output.get(1);
            ids = output.get(2);
            FullText = output.get(3);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Descriptions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            strID.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    }).execute("http://192.168.1.106:8000/database/news/g/?format=json");

}
}
```

the Toast that i made it in onRefresh print right data but Gui doesn't refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this `Descriptions = output.get(0);`, `Descriptions` will start pointing to new list and lost the reference to the list that is being used by the adapter so list with adapter and list in current are no longer same, hence the issue

Instead of this

```
Descriptions = output.get(0);
titles = output.get(1);
ids = output.get(2);
FullText = output.get(3);
```

Use

```
// inside on refresh
data.clear();
//...code
Descriptions.addAll(output.get(0));
titles.addAll(get(1));
ids.addAll(get(2));
FullText.addAll(get(3));
getData();
```

Comment: i should do this in onCreate or onRefresh or both !!?

Comment: @MoatazMahmoud try the update and do it inside `onrefresh`, the code needs lot of refactoring though

Comment: just follow the answer , `//...code` mean don't touch the rest of the code except the mentioned one